# Is the ELSE of an IF (p) statement including a method the "NOT METHOD" (not p)?

Tags: if-statement, methods, boolean, return

If I write a statement:

```
if(!(method())  
{  
    // do something  
}    
else  
{  
    //do something  
}
```

And method returns a boolean value, is the else - **without** writing else if (method() - automatically the opposite of if, i.e. does else have a relationship to the method called in the opening if statement?

Comment: I am trying to minimize overhead and visible code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, if method on IF return TRUE, as it's negated, ELSE statement will execute.

It's like:

```
if(!myMethod()) {

    //RUN SOMETHING
}
else {
    //RUN OTHER THING HERE
}
```

If MyMethod Returns "TRUE", the if statement will se a "FALSE" because it's inverting it, so as it's not true, will run the ELSE code (//RUN OTHER THING).

Comment: Ah, okay. Now I understand. Thank you @Ivan Verges. If something is the case, the only possibility for the else - logically speaking - is that it is not the case. So, if you evaluate for 'is-the-case' and that returns false, then you have your else condition: 'not-the-case'. Sorry for the weird wording.

Comment: Yeah, The Else Statement Needs An If That Evaluate To FALSE To Execute, You Can't Use An ELSE Without An IF.

Answer (score 0):

Yes - implicitly, `IF .. ELSE` is a boolean test that essentially looks like this:

```
IF (condition)
{
<< condition evaluated to TRUE >>
}
ELSE
{
<< condition evaluated to FALSE >>
}
```